# How to get totalcount in php laravel from SoapClient Response

Tags: php, soap-client

How can I get `totalcount` in php laravel?

```
object(stdClass)[268]
public 'ApprovedLoanRequestsResult' => 
object(stdClass)[269]
public 'totalCount' => int 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have `totalCount` as a member inside an `stdClass` object inside an `stdClass` object. You can get it like this

```
yourobject->ApprovedLoanRequestsResult->totalCount
```

assuming that the name of the outer object is `yourobject`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the response parameter with this:

$response  = "";
$totalCountResponse = $response->totalCount;

It should work.